# Incompatibility between -prune and -delete in find command?

Tags: find, delete

The manpage for `find` says:

```
   -prune True;  if  the file is a directory, do not descend into it. If -depth is 
          given, false; no effect.  Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot 
          usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

What is the meaning of the last sentence? Can't one usefully run the below command...

```
find /path/ -prune -type f -ctime +15 -delete
```

... to find and delete all files last changed more than 15 days ago in `/path/` **but not in the subdirectories under** `/path/`? I think it's a perfectly valid use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that `-prune` is ineffective if `-depth` is also used 
and `-delete` *implies* `-depth`.

As for the use case you're asking about, I've always used `-maxdepth X`.

For example

```
find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -ctime +15 -delete
```

will do.

Comment: You're right.  *Use of -delete automatically turns on the `-depth' option.*, says the manpage just a few lines before.  Guess I completely missed out that bit.